# Javascript append notification, animate and delete

Tags: javascript, css

I have a js function called show_alert.

```
function show_alert(type='info', $message) {

$('.notifications-area').append(' \
    <div class="notification opened ' + type + '"> \
        <h5>' + $message + '</h5> \
    </div> \
');

setTimeout(function(){
    $('.notification').addClass('closed');
  }, 4000);
}
```

The **opened** and **closed** css classes contain some keyframes, the opened one making it come up, and the closed makes it fade away. I want to remove the html also after the closed animation takes place.

Comment: You forgot to describe your problem I think? Is your problem that you cannot find out when the keyframe is finished so you can call .remove() on the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but something like this should work:

```
function show_alert(type='info', $message) {
  var notification = $('<your notification element html here/>');

  $('.notifications-area').append(notification);

  setTimeout(function(){
    notification.addClass('closed');
  }, 4000);

  setTimeout(function(){
    notification.remove();
  }, 8000);
}
```

By creating the element for your notification first and assigning it to a variable, you have a reference to it you can use later on - without the need for any IDs, or any methods that would have to go and “find” the element in the DOM first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) api.

You can do something like this.

```
function show_alert(type='info', $message) {
  var randomId = getRandomId ();

  $('.notifications-area').append(' \
    <div id="' + randomId + '" class="notification opened ' + type + '"> \
        <h5>' + $message + '</h5> \
    </div> \
  ');

setTimeout(function(){
    $('#' + randomId).addClass('closed');
    // you still have the randomId,
    $('#' + randomId).remove();
  }, 4000);
}}
```

Comment: I know, but I need to specify which alert to close, I may have more alerts, need some kind of reference to the current alert.

Comment: Add an ID (generate it randomly) and associate it with the notification. Then use the closed notification's id to remove it. This will help you to uniquely identify your notifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.notification').addClass('closed');

var duration = {YOUR CSS TRANSITION DURATION};

setTimeout(function(){
  $('.notification').remove();
}, duration);
```

So after your animation jquery will remove your DOM from html.